# Unable to Send ISO 8583 Messages Through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, iso8583, jpos

I am using ISO8583 Sampler in JMeter for Sending ISO Messages, i had put Necessary Plugins & JAR files like JPOS. However i get "**MTI not available**" in the Sampler Response

**Settings in ISO8583 Connection Configuration**

Packager Configuration :- test-generic-validating-packager.xml file from JPOS 2.1.4

```
Host Name :- 192.168.1.104
Port Number :- 8080
```

**Field wise Data in ISO8583 Sampler**

```
003 380000      
011 00000000XXXX        
012 20200821${__time(HHmmss,)}      
017 20200821        
024 200     
032 0       
034 000000      
041 0000000000000MBK        
049 INR     
102 IBKL  01310200000XXXX       
123 MBK
```

**Output of Sampler**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2020-08-21 17:18:09 IST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 
Response message: org.jpos.iso.ISOException: MTI not available
```

When i put MTI as 1200 or 0800 in the ISO Sampler, JMeter is unable to send the Request to the Server

Can someone help me out in this??

The same i able to process with Neoload Tool..

Comment: Hi, that exception usually happens if you try to send a message without MTI, how are you setting the MTI? In the field you put the field 0, i.e. the MTI is not present. Also is there some more detailed logs you can share?

Comment: Thank You, I added Field 0 as per document, now it Worked..

Answer (score 3):

As per this documentation aren’t you missing the configuration of field 0 for MTI:

- https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-iso8583#iso8583-sampler

Comment: Thank You, i added field 0 as per format, now working..

Comment: I tried Upvoting.. it's telling me that 15 Ratings some required, however votes recorded etc..

Comment: yes you need to have more points. But you can accept answer by clicking on the check sign at the left of the answer. Thanks

Comment: It is still not accepted, can you double check ? There should be a green check sign next to it.Thank you